# Why I can't get the result when I using localhost?

Tags: http, request

My computer ip is 192.168.11.3, and I do my coding, and I send getJSON request to localhost, the getJSON path is something like this:

http://localhost:8080/requestJSON.php

it works fine when I go to the path:

http://localhost:8080/myApplication.php

But when I changed it to 192.168.11.3, like this :

http://192.168.11.3:8080/myApplication.php

I use the same code, the getJSON still request the JSON in

http://localhost:8080/requestJSON.php

But I can't get what I want.  I use this two links in my same computer, it should be the same, when I access localhost, and 192.168.11.3.  What happens? thank you.

Comment: What do you get when accessing the url with IP instead of localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose one possibility is that your browser is enforcing the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) before trying to resolve the address.  Try changing the `requestJSON.php` URL to match the address of the URL you're requesting and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to request the JSON from the same host as the page from which you're requesting it. So for instance `http://192.168.11.3:8080/myApplication.php` needs to request it from `http://192.168.11.3:8080/requestJSON.php`. The easiest way to do this is to use a relative URL in the request.